# 'Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start"'

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, time-series

How do I get surface temperature variation with a time series chart?

I have tried the same code on different data but it does not work with this one.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("JAXA/GCOM-C/L3/OCEAN/SST/V3")
            .filterDate('2023-01-24', '2023-02-03')
            // filter to daytime data only
            .filter(ee.Filter.eq("SATELLITE_DIRECTION", "D"));
print(dataset);
// Clip the dataset to the geometry
var clipped = dataset.mean().clip(geometry).select('SST_AVE').set('system:time_start', dataset.get('system:time_start'));

// Multiply with slope coefficient and add offset
var scaled = clipped.multiply(0.0012).add(-10);

// Define the visualization parameters
var vis = {
  bands: ['SST_AVE'],
  min: 0,
  max: 10,
  palette: ['000000', '005aff', '43c8c8', 'fff700', 'ff0000'],
};

Map.centerObject(geometry, 10);
Map.addLayer(scaled, vis, "Clipped and scaled SST");

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: scaled,
  region: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start',
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a single image to the chart (the mean over time) where an image collection is expected. You will want to scale every image in the collection. That's done through `map()`. The `copyProperties()` call is to ensure you actually retain `system:time_start` after scaling. Use `clip()` only when needed, and as late in the processing as possible.

```
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("JAXA/GCOM-C/L3/OCEAN/SST/V3")
  .filterDate('2023-01-24', '2023-02-03')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq("SATELLITE_DIRECTION", "D"))
  .map(function(image) {
    return image
      .select('SST_AVE')
      .multiply(0.0012).add(-10)
      .copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames())
  })

var vis = {bands: ['SST_AVE'], min: 0, max: 10, palette: ['000000', '005aff', '43c8c8', 'fff700', 'ff0000']}
Map.addLayer(imageCollection.mean().clip(geometry), vis, "Clipped and scaled SST")
Map.centerObject(geometry, 10)

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: imageCollection,
  region: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000
})

print(chart)
```